# getting metadata from table sql server (php)

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to get metadata from the tables on my database (sql server).
I execute the query to get that metadata on Sql Management Studio and it works but on php script show that error when i do : $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res):
"Unexpected SQL type encountered in calc_string_size."

I suspected that the problem was on the build of the query string on the php but it's not because i printed that query and it's correct.

The problem appears when i added a field on the select (column description).

Anyone know that problem?

Answer (score 4):

You probably got

`sql_variant`

somewhere in your query.
That throws an error -> you have to cast the specific columns as 
`VARCHAR`

Answer (score 2):

First of all thank you for answer.

my code:

$res=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql); /*that part is working*/
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)){ /* it's here that the error occurs
(...)
}

On the query sql if i remove the field (description) on select that works 100%

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved.
I did a cast to that description field and it works.
For the next people who will try get metadata from a table on sql server and need the description field it's necessary do cast to that field to varchar.
Thank you!